# How to best check if a SQL table contents have not changed?

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have the following table named "contacts":

```
id|name|age
1|John|5
2|Amy|2
3|Eric|6
```

Is there some easy way to check whether or not this table changes much like how a sha/md5 hash works when getting the checksum for a file on your computer?

So for example, if a new row was added to this table, or if a value was changed within the table, the "hash" or some generated value shows that the table has changed.

If there is no direct mechanism, what is the best way to do this (could be some arbirary hash mechanism, as long as the method puts emphasis on performance and minimizing latency)? Could it be applied to multiple tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if something has changed, you need something to compare. For example a date. You can add a table with two columns, the tablename and the timestamp, and program a trigger for the events on the table you are interested to control, so this trigger will update the timestamp column of this control table.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct mechanism to get that information through SQL.

You could consider adding an additional LastModified column to each row.  To know the last time the table was modified, select the maximum value for that column.

You could achieve a similar outcome by using a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html) on the table for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE, which updates a separate table with the last modified timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If the table isn't too big, you could take a copy of the entire table. When you want to check for changes, you can then query the old vs. new data.

```
drop table  backup_table_name;
CREATE TABLE backup_table_name LIKE table_name;
INSERT INTO backup_table_name SELECT * FROM `table_name`;
```